# How to simulate data matrix filling

Tags: r, modeling, simulation

Suppose you can measure 3 properties $A, B, C$ for any object.
However, making these measurements has a cost, so if you have, say, 100 objects, you can't fill the data matrix with 300 data points.
Suppose you can measure $A$ for $p_A = 10\%$ of the objects, $B$ for $p_B = 25\%$ and $C$ for $p_C = 40\%$.
If all measurements are made independently, you will probably have some objects that have no measurement for any property, some that have a measurement only for $A$, only for $B$, for $A$ and $B$, etc., and the probability of each of these occurrences is easily calculated.
E.g. the probability of cases with no measurements (i.e. the fraction of objects with no data for any of the properties) is:

$P(\bar A, \bar B, \bar C) = (1-p_A) \cdot (1-p_B) \cdot (1-p_C) = (1-0.1) \cdot (1-0.25) \cdot (1-0.4) = 0.405$

A simulation in $R$ seems to confirm this:

```
N = 10000

set.seed(1784)

d.A <- as.numeric(runif(N) <= 0.1)
d.B <- as.numeric(runif(N) <= 0.25)
d.C <- as.numeric(runif(N) <= 0.4)

s <- paste(d.A,d.B,d.C)

mean(s == "0 0 0")
#[1] 0.4048
```

`d.A` is a binary vector indicating whether its n-th element has (1) or hasn't got (0) data for property $A$, and similarly for $B$ and $C$. So a list of objects with the properties they have data for is easily obtained:

```
d <- data.frame("OBJ" = c((1:N)[as.logical(d.A)],(1:N)[as.logical(d.B)],(1:N)[as.logical(d.C)]), "PROP" = c(LETTERS[d.A*1],LETTERS[d.B*2],LETTERS[d.C*3]))
d <- d[order(d$OBJ),]
head(d,10)
#     OBJ PROP
#1006   2    B
#3489   3    C
#3490   5    C
#3491   6    C
#1007   7    B
#1      8    A
#3492   9    C
#1008  10    B
#1009  11    B
#3493  11    C
```

So for instance, object 1 isn't there, i.e. it has no data for any property; object 2 has data only for $B$; ...; object 11 has data for $B$ and $C$.

Incidentally, `d` can be converted back to a matrix by `xtabs`, which can be useful for some further computation:

```
head(xtabs(~OBJ+PROP,d))
#   PROP
#OBJ A B C
#  2 0 1 0
#  3 0 0 1
#  5 0 0 1
#  6 0 0 1
#  7 0 1 0
#  8 1 0 0
```

Now, if you wanted to use these data for modelling, you would indeed only be interested in objects that have data *for at least one property*. Objects with no data for any property are little use in that context.
However, this has the effect of changing the percentage of "data filling" for each property.

Looking at the percentages obtained by simulation:

```
mean(d.A)
#[1] 0.1005
mean(d.B)
#[1] 0.2483
mean(d.C)
#[1] 0.4027
```

i.e. pretty close to the intended $p_A, p_B, p_C$.
When the objects with no data are removed:

```
d.A.2 <- d.A[s != "0 0 0"]
d.B.2 <- d.B[s != "0 0 0"]
d.C.2 <- d.C[s != "0 0 0"]

mean(d.A.2)
#[1] 0.1688508
mean(d.B.2)
#[1] 0.4171707
mean(d.C.2)
#[1] 0.6765793
```

which is the same as:

```
table(d$PROP)/length(unique(d$OBJ))

#        A         B         C 
#0.1688508 0.4171707 0.6765793
```

It is easy to show that the new percentages are just the old ones "re-scaled" by the fraction of non-removed objects:

$p_A' = \frac {p_A} {1-(1-p_A) \cdot (1-p_B) \cdot (1-p_C)}, p_B' = \frac {p_B} {1-(1-p_A) \cdot (1-p_B) \cdot (1-p_C)}, p_C' = \frac {p_C} {1-(1-p_A) \cdot (1-p_B) \cdot (1-p_C)}$

```
0.1/(1-0.405)
#[1] 0.1680672
0.25/(1-0.405)
#[1] 0.4201681
0.4/(1-0.405)
#[1] 0.6722689
```

Now here's my question: suppose you don't know $p_A, p_B, p_C$, but only the "final" percentages $p_A', p_B', p_C'$.

**How would you go about making a simulated `d`, i.e. a simulated matrix data filling, for such a set, so that the *final* percentages (after removing objects with no data) match your requirements ?**

Not necessarily going via the `d.A` vectors; if `d` can be simulated directly, even better, but try as I might, I could not find a simple way to do it.

Comment: You can estimate the common factor (fraction of non-removed) by dividing pairs among $(p_A', p_B', p_C')$ and thereby find the original probabilities. Once you have those, you can simulate each vector if you know the total sample size. Is that enough to answer your question?

Comment: @MaximilianAigner : thank you but I don't understand how you would do that. When I take a ratio of two $p_X'$ I eliminate the denominator, I do not estimate it. I would end up with 2 independent equations with 3 variables, so I cannot know $p_A,p_B,p_C$. If you know how to do it please let me know. And yes, I could solve the original equations, but already with 3 properties they are quite complicated, imagine with 10, 20, 100 properties (which can happen in real cases). I wanted to know if it's possible to simulate the final system directly without finding back the original $p_A,p_B,p_C$.

Comment: Sorry, that's right -- it's adding the $p'$ that yields the common factor. I don't know how you would simulate without the original probabilities, sorry.

Comment: @MaximilianAigner : actually, your suggestion is useful. I can calculate the ratios between each $p_X_i$ and the largest $p_X$, in this example $p_A / p_C = 0.25$ and $p_B / p_C = 0.617$. This allows me to turn the last equation into a univariate expression: $0.676 = \frac {p_C} {1-(1-0.25 p_C) \cdot (1-0.617 p_C) \cdot (1-p_C)}$, which I can solve numerically to get $p_C$, and $p_A, p_B$ by back-substitution. At least one does not have to solve a multivariate system.